# Error: Expected ')' before 'char' error in C

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am new at C and especially pointers. I would appreciate any help.

```
int checkDiamonds(cor_row,cor_collumn,char *arr2)
{
    if (*(arr2 + cor_row*7 + cor_collumn)=='*')

        return 1;

    else
        return 0;
}
```

This is one of the functions I'm using for my code and I couldn't understand why it keeps giving me this error: `Expected ')' before 'char'`.

Comment: Compilers are notorious for giving poor error messages. so don't feel bad.  Sadly, the "front end" is written to be fast, so it reports an error at the point it figured out the grammar was broken, not necessarily where your issue actually is.  It does not want to spend a lot of time figuring out what you are trying to do.  It would be good if there were 2 different versions of the front-end compiler, one that's fast, another that provides better error messages.

Comment: @franji1 Compilers are pretty good at giving the error messages, if you take them in the context and look at the line number which is omitted in the question.

Comment: @franji1 The quality of error messages has almost nothing to do with parsing performance. Instead, it’s simply *a lot harder* to write compilers to give good error messages. And by “harder” I mean both complicated, and making the parsing code (substantially) more complex.

Comment: The fix to the error had absolutely NOTHING to do with missing a ')' around char, correct?  That is a bad error message.  See @vlad from moscow explanation.  The error message ASSUMED the issue was that it was malformed identifier list.  Wrong assumption.  It was a malformed parameter type list.  It could have generated 2 different errors based on each of these assumptions.  THAT is what I am talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function declaration that at the same time is its definition can either use an identifier list or a parameter type list but not the both simultaneously.

So this function definition

```
int checkDiamonds(cor_row,cor_collumn,char *arr2)
{
    if (*(arr2 + cor_row*7 + cor_collumn)=='*')

        return 1;

    else
        return 0;
}
```

is parsed by the compiler as a function that has an identifier list but then it encountered a type specifier.

So you need to use either an identifier list or a parameter type list. Of course it is better to use a parameter type list providing the function prototype for the compiler.

For example your function could be declared like

```
int checkDiamonds( size_t cor_row,size_t cor_collumn, const char *arr2)
{
    return *( arr2 + cor_row*7 + cor_collumn ) == '*';
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program that shows the difference between using an identifier list and parameter type list in a function declaration that at the same time is a function definition.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( s, n )
const char *s; size_t n;
{
    puts( s + n );
}

void g( const char *s, size_t n )
{
    puts( s + n );
}

int main(void) 
{
    f( "One Two", 0 );
    g( "One Two", 4 );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
One Two
Two
```

Comment: +1 Great explanation of the grammatical differences that caused the specific compiler error - explaining WHY they are getting THAT error (but NOT "what's wrong with my code", which is what a lot of people think the answer needs to be).  Your answer explains "why" OP was getting the error (actual OP question) - not just "how to fix it".

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the type of your parameters, for example:

```
int checkDiamonds(int cor_row, int cor_collumn, char *arr2)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The modern way to define your function is with a type for each parameter:

```
int checkDiamonds(int cor_row, int cor_collumn, char *arr2)
{
    …
}
```

To support old source code, a function can still be defined with the types separately:

```
int checkDiamonds(cor_row, cor_collumn, arr2)
int cor_row;
int cor_collumn;
char *arr2;
{
    …
}
```

Because the compiler saw `int checkDiamonds(cor_row,cor_collumn`, it expected the next thing to be another parameter name or a closing parentheses. When it saw a type, `char`, instead, that was unexpected, so complained, telling you it expected a `)` rather than `char`.

There are other differences between the two definition methods. The first distinguishes the types better and should be used in new code.